# Should the inclusion of @RequestParam in a Controller method prevent the returned page from opening?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-boot

I have a Controller class with a number of methods that receive **or** send data to **or** from JSP pages. All of these methods work correctly however when I try to receive data **and** print data in the same method the page I try to return won't open

For example, this method will successfully print an ArrayList of objects to the `commuteChecker` JSP page when `/commuteCheckerPage`is called from the front end:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/commuteCheckerPage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String commuteChecker(@Valid Commutes commutes, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {

     Authentication loggedInUser = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
      String username = loggedInUser.getName(); // Authentication for 

      commutesRepository.save(commutes);
      User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);

      List<Commutes> savedCommutes = user.getSavedCommutes();
      for (int i = 0; i < savedCommutes.size(); i++) {
          model.addAttribute("savedCommutes", savedCommutes);
      }

    return "commuteChecker";
}
```

Similarly when `/skip` is called from the front end the `welcome` page is successfully returned/opened.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/skip", method = RequestMethod.GET) 
public String Skip() {
    return "welcome";
}
```

It seems when I include `@RequestParam` to receive data **and then** attempt to add `model.addAttribute` to print this data to a page, the code within the method will work (the print debug prints the correct value) but the `houseprice`JSP page won't open. In the example below I take in a `latitude` and `longitude` value, query a database and calculate an average house price and the number of houses from the query based on a radius around the `latitude` and `longitude` values provided.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/parseHousePrice", method={RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET})
    public @ResponseBody String parseHousePrice(HousePrice housePrice, 
                                                @RequestParam("latitude") double latitude,             
                                                @RequestParam("longitude") double longitude,                                                           
                                                Model model) {

// Running method that queries PostgreSQL for average price
double housePriceAverage = parseHousePrice.ParseHousePrice(latitude, longitude);

// Adding results from PostgreSQL db to array to get number of houses
List<Double> housePriceList = parseHousePrice.getList();
int housePriceListSize = housePriceList.size();

// Simple println  debugger
System.out.println("The average house price for this area is: " + housePriceAverage + " based on " + housePriceListSize + " property prices in this area");

// Im trying to pass the two values calculated above to houseprice.jsp
model.addAttribute("houseprice", housePriceAverage);
model.addAttribute("housepricelistsize", housePriceListSize);

// Page I'm trying to load but wont open
return "houseprice";
}
```

But as I said previously the page simply won't open. I've tried a number of different ways to implement this i.e.`ModelAndView` and `HttpSession` instead of using a `Model` and neither will load the page, which is leading me to believe I can't receive and send data within the same controller method. Is this correct and if so is there a way to work around this?

Comment: Do you get any error message? In the console

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here

```
public @ResponseBody String parseHousePrice(HousePrice housePrice, 
                                            @RequestParam("latitude") double latitude,             
                                            @RequestParam("longitude") double longitude,                                                           
                                            Model model)...
```

it should be like this

```
public String parseHousePrice(HousePrice housePrice, 
                                            @RequestParam("latitude") double latitude,             
                                            @RequestParam("longitude") double longitude,                                                           
                                            Model model)...
```

remove the **@ResponseBody** that was making the controller writing to the body of reponse instead of returning a view

Comment: try doing the http request in a separate program like "Postman" and tell us what is the response